# Can't import spacy

Tags: python, spacy, text-mining

i've been trying to import **spacy** but everytime an error appears  as a result.
I used this line to install the package :

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

then i tried to **import spacy** and it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-76a01d9c502b> in <module>
----> 1 import spacy

~\Python\Text\spacy.py in <module>
      9 import spacy
     10 # Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, and NER
---> 11 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
     12 # Process whole documents
     13 text = ("When Sebastian Thrun started working on self-driving cars at "

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'spacy' has no attribute 'load' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Can anybody help me.

Comment: It seems like you named your file `spacy.py`, so python tries to import your own script. Rename your file.

Comment: How do you find the "spacy.py" file, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the file you are working in is named `spacy.py`, which is interfering with the spacy module. So you should rename your file to something other than "spacy".